# Avoid table function in where clause?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-functions

I have added table function in the `where` clause.

[image]

```
select cmp_id, acno_code, sl_type, sl_code, 0 op_Dr, 0 op_cr, 0 tr_Dr, sum(amount) tr_Cr                                                  
from vf_finance                    
where cmp_id =@cmp_id1         
and unitcode in (select * from UTILfn_Split( @unit_code,',') )   
and stat_code in ('AT','PR' )        
--and pc_code  in (select * from UTILfn_Split( @sba,',') )        
AND DOC_dT >=convert(datetime,@from_date,103) and doc_Dt <= convert(datetime,@to_date,103)                                                  
and amount < 0                     
GROUP BY cmp_id, acno_code, sl_type, sl_code                                                   
)  as gl                                                 
inner join ps_Accmas acc on acc.cmp_id = gl.cmp_id and acc.acno_Code = gl.acno_code                                                   
inner join ps_owner o on gl.cmp_id = o.cmp_id                                                   
left outer join view_sl_code sl on gl.cmp_id = sl.cmp_id and gl.sl_type = sl.sl_type and gl.sl_Code = sl.sl_Code                                                  
inner join ps_slType slt on gl.cmp_id = slt.cmp_id and gl.sl_Type = slt.sl_type  
where  sl.sl_type in (select * from UTILfn_Split( @sl_type,',') )     
and acc.acno_code in(select * from UTILfn_Split( @facno_code,',') )                             
group by gl.cmp_id, gl.acno_code,gl.sl_code,gl.sl_type,slt.sl_DEsc,acc.acno_DEsc, sl.sl_DEsc, o.owner_name                  
order by gl.cmp_id, gl.acno_code,gl.sl_code,gl.sl_type
```

Can anyone please suggest how I can avoid function in `where` clause?

Comment: Have you tried `inner join UTILfn_Split(@sl_type, ',') sl2 on sl2.Value=sl.sl_type`? Also, SQL Server 2016 and later has the builtin [`STRING_SPLIT() function`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: check your query again, `)  as gl ` it seems there is no starting bracket....check this and correct it first

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. There are some issues in this existing query which I'll point first

First `unitcode in (select * from UTILfn_Split( @unit_code,',')` here you must use one column name instead of `*`, although i don't know about your function `UTILfn_Split` but still mention column name is preferable.

for your query you may use `inner join` instead of `in` with function having return type table.

Instead of

```
sl.sl_type in (select * from UTILfn_Split( @sl_type,',') )
```

You may try this

```
yourtble as sl inner join 
(select value from UTILfn_Split( @sl_type,',') as t2 
on sl.sl_type = t2.[value]     ---- here column name with t2 depends on your function, 
---what table structure is returning, in your case it is [value]
```

Comment: here is my return type in the function 
returns @ValueTable table ([Value] nvarchar(max))

Comment: you may replace all of your `in` clause with `inner join` like i did in above code...